# How do I create an online refund for an order that has not been shipped yet?

Tags: payment-gateway

My Google-fu is failing me on this one, however, I want to be able to do a complete refund online for an order that has not been shipped yet.

The gateway (Barclaycard's one) works fine for complete online refunds, and yes I can do an offline refund, however, I would like to be able to refund (make a credit note in Magento parlance) with it coming off the customer's card and without having to make a delivery.

Any ideas? Is there a config setting on a payment gateway that allows for this?

Answer (score 1):

Magento calls a refund a *Credit Memo*.

You can create a Credit Memo as soon as there is an invoice associated with the order.
It is not required to create a shipment.

It's not possible to create a Credit Memo for an order without an invoice, because (in Magento) all Payments are associated with an invoice.